# Can I use a similar AC adapter with different input but the same output?

Tags: voltage, ac, output, input, telephone

I have a landline telephone from Japan. The owners manual says only use OUR AC adapter, {Input 100v 50/60Hz 8VA - Output DC 11V 430mA}

I want to use this in North America - can I use a AC adapter rated for Input 120 V/Output DC 11V ~430mA without damaging the telephone?

Thanks.

Comment: probably off-topic

Comment: Most likley yes. The reason for writing "our" is EMC and general liability.

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly yes.  But be careful.  Many wall warts (AC adapters) are linear power supplies with no regulation.  At low output currents the output voltage can be significantly above the rated value.  Switching wall warts are regulated, often down to zero load current.  Do you know which kind you have?

Comment: No, I am not sure what kind I have. Is there a way to tell without opening up the adapter? The sticker just has the input/output and polarity..

Comment: @muffin -- a linear wall wart will feel like holding a brick compared to the feather of a switching wall wart :) (that's because the transformer core in a linear wall wart is basically a brick of laminated steel ;)

Comment: for example, the power adapter that came with your cell phone, is most likely a switching power adapter

Comment: if the power supply accepts a continuous wide range of input voltages  (eg: 90 to 260v) its output is almost certainly regulated, using a regulated supply on a device that does not require one is unlikely to cause damage

Comment: if it says "switching" or "transformer", then you know. effeciency level 5 = smps too.

Comment: The shape also is a clue.  Linear warts tend to be closer to a cube in shape, while switchers are more rectangular (unequal dimensions).